# How do I publish a React App to a website?

Tags: reactjs

I am a complete newb to Visual Studio Code and React Apps, so please forgive my *complete* lack of knowledge when it comes to coding.

I have just created a React App in Visual Studio Code and I do not have a clue about how I Export/Publish it to a website. I followed a YouTube video to create the app and after I type 'npm run dev' in the terminal, I get a localhost address so that I can view the app and use it in my browser.

Please can you tell me how I can use the localhost address (or convert/deploy it) in a Squarespace or a WordPress website, so that I can make the app usable for the public?

Thank you.

Comment: look into github pages or netlify

Answer (score 1):

To publish an App developed in React, you can use a free CloudComputing service. At the moment, I recommend use [Render](https://render.com/) platform, its free and you don´t need a credit card to sign in.

In addition, I list some documentation that will help you to deploy your app:

- [Oficial Render documentation for React deploys](https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app)
- [Video tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=deploy%20react%20in%20render&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFybmw1e_9AhXUVTABHULNAVoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=758&dpr=1.25#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:72c675e6,vid:YwFUjauIj0Q)
- [Medium Post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-render-611ef3aca84a)

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you need to find a place to buy/rent a server, which may cost money, or you can find it for free for a trial run on some website. Firebase is an example here. You then host your website on the server.

If you want to host it locally, and let people from around the internet access the website, you need to ask your ISP to get you a static IP address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/8-ways-deploy-react-app-free/#github-pages), here are the way to deploy a `create-react-app` to Github Pages:

1. Create a git repository, link your project to it then push it.
2. install github dependency: `npm install --save gh-pages`
3. Edit your `packages.json`

```json
{
  "homepage": "https://<my-github-username>.github.io/my-app"
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
  }
}
```

4. Deploy your site by running: `npm run deploy`